# Close all Mac Terminal windows, but the one running a script

Tags: mac, terminal, script, applescript

I am trying to create a shell script that runs a python simulation programing in 4 terminal windows.  I have the script that launches the program four times in four separate terminal windows(total of 5 windows, 4 for the python programs, and one to control the other terminal windows).  I want to now create a script that I can run in the control terminal window that closes and kills the programs of the other four terminal windows, but still have the control one open.

What I have so far is something like this

```
#!/bin/sh

osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" 
do script "killall python"
end tell'
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to quit'
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to open'
```

The problem is that the last line doesn't work because it closes all the windows including the one the script is executing in.  I am not really familiar with shell or apple script so any help would be welcomed. I posted on Stack, but I think this might be a better place for an automation type question.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the id of the "Main" window to a variable and then at the end of the script, close all windows whose id does not match that of the "Main" window. The AppleScript portion can be along these lines:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set mainID to id of front window
    -- insert your code
    close (every window whose id ≠ mainID)
end tell
```

EDIT

```
#!/bin/sh

killall python

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'set mainID to id of front window' -e 'close (every window whose id ≠ mainID)' -e 'end tell'
```

Comment: I am a total noobie when it comes to apple script and sh scripting can you edit the answer to function code, and for the "insert your code" part I would just killall python then have the rest close all windows

Comment: You only want to use osascript for AppleScript commands, not ones that can be executed in the shell (killall python).

Answer (score 1):

If the window running the script is frontmost and Terminal doesn't ask for confirmation when closing the other windows, you could try something like this.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    close rest of (get windows)
end tell
```

Comment: The `windows` list is ordered as they are displayed from front to back, and `rest of` means *all but the first one*.